# Регулярные выражения. PHP

Tags: apache-modules, регулярные-выражения, mod_rewrite

Всем доброго времени суток
У меня такой вопрос, как через регулярки можно сделать такое, что в адресной браузера ссылка одна, но на самом деле страница, которая отображается, грузиться по др. ссылки?
К примеру, в адресной строке http://site.ru/ но отображается страница http://site.ru/page.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это надо писать регулярки в RewriteRule/RewriteCond. PHP тут не при чем.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.*) page.php?q=$1
```

Это в htaccess. Подробнее - ищите mod_rewrite можно прямо тут. Ну или задавайе кнкретный вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Это настраивается либо в конфиге сервера.
Либо, если Вы пишете под фреймворком, то прописывается в роутах.

Comment: просто мне нужно сделать так: если пользователь залогинен, то по ссылке http://site.ru/ отображается одня страница (его профиль)
а если нет, то отбражается страница входа

Comment: Так Вы проверяйте массив $_POST, если там данные есть, и они соответствуют даным в БД, то отображать Вашу страничку, если нет, то другу. Как отображать очень много способов. Например через инклуд.

Comment: а вот как через инклуд?

Comment: [php.su](http://php.su/functions/?include_once)  
Просто сделайте вначале файла проверку, и в зависимости от результата подключайте разные шаблоны...